# Android WebView Fails to Completely Render Content Until User Interaction

Tags: android, webkit, webview, scroll, render

I have a custom class extending WebView that displays HTML content. When the user clicks a link in the HTML document, I calculate an X value to scroll to, and then use scrollTo(x,y) to show that location via a runnable (see below)

```
 post( new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                scrollTo( x, 0 );
                MyWebView.this.invalidate();
                MyWebView.this.buildDrawingCache();
                MyWebView.this.refreshDrawableState();
                MyWebView.this.postInvalidate();
            }
        } );
```

After scrolling, there is a chance that the webview will fail to render the entire document. Rectangular chunks of white space are shown where text should be, with seemingly random placement each time. Here is a screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlsKj.jpg

When I touch the webview to scroll, it will immediately render the missing portions.

So far this behavior is constrained to the Samsung Galaxy 10.1" tablet.

Does anyone know a workaround / how to force webkit to re-render the page?

Comment: Any luck here?  Having a similar problem.  This works fine in Jelly Bean, but is a constant issue in ICS.

Comment: I have this exact issue even on Jelly bean. Its working fine on Kitkat though.

Answer (score 6):

Well i am having the exact same problem here with that tablet, the only difference is that i am using **[iscroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4)** to do all the scrolling. The solution i am using for this problem is to "scroll" via JavaScript a hidden DIV and that fixed the problem. i hope this can help anyone with the same problem. If you use iscroll they have a method to "scroll" to a fixed position, maybe that can help you also, if not is not that hard to detect the **touchmove** or **mousemove** events. **The point here is that you just need to fake a scroll anywhere on the html even if is not visible.**