# Android Webview: Detect when rendering is finished

Tags: android, android-webview, snapshot

I want to snapshot the WebView after the WebView is loaded. However, the returned bitmap is always null because the render  hasn't loaded completed even though I use `onPageFinished`. 
I search on Internet and people suggest to use `WebView.PictureListener`, but **this function is deprecated in API 12**.

Some codes

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private WebView mButterflyWebView;

    /**
     * Gets html content from the assets folder.
     */
    private String getHtmlFromAsset() {
        InputStream is;
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        String htmlString = null;
        try {
            is = getAssets().open(getString(R.string.butterfly_html));
            if (is != null) {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(is));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    builder.append(line);
                }

                htmlString = builder.toString();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return htmlString;
    }

    /**
     * Initializes views, controls...
     */ 

    private void init() {
        mButterflyWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.butterfly_webview);

        mButterflyWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {


            if (newProgress == 100){
                if (capturePictureWebView() != null){
                    saveBitmapToFile(capturePictureWebView());
                }
            }
        }
    });

    }

    /**
     * Loads html page with the content.
     */
    private void loadHtmlPage() {
        String htmlString = getHtmlFromAsset();
        if (htmlString != null)
            mButterflyWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(
                    "file:///android_asset/images/", htmlString, "text/html",
                    "UTF-8", null);

        else
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.no_such_page, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
    }

    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        init();
        loadHtmlPage();
    }

    private Bitmap capturePictureWebView() {
        mButterflyWebView.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
        mButterflyWebView.layout(0, 0, mButterflyWebView.getMeasuredWidth(),
                mButterflyWebView.getMeasuredHeight());
        mButterflyWebView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        mButterflyWebView.buildDrawingCache();

        if (mButterflyWebView.getMeasuredWidth() == 0 || mButterflyWebView.getMeasuredHeight() == 0){
            return null;
        }
        Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(720, 1280, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        System.out.println("width=" + mButterflyWebView.getMeasuredWidth());
        System.out.println("height=" + mButterflyWebView.getMeasuredHeight());
        Canvas bigcanvas = new Canvas(bm);
//        bigcanvas.scale(720/mButterflyWebView.getMeasuredWidth(), 1280/mButterflyWebView.getMeasuredHeight());
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        int iHeight = bm.getHeight();
        bigcanvas.drawBitmap(bm, 0, iHeight, paint);
        mButterflyWebView.draw(bigcanvas);
        return bm;
    }

    private void saveBitmapToFile(Bitmap bitmap) {
        try {

            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("/storage/sdcard0/a.png");
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I got the very detailed for this problem. This explains why it always returns null bitmap.

**Every change in my app are triggered by a user action so I came up with a modified version that only trigger invalidate() after a touchEvent**

Thank for all your help.

[Android WebView renders blank/white, view doesn't update on css changes or HTML changes, animations are choppy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13500452/android-webview-renders-blank-white-view-doesnt-update-on-css-changes-or-html)

Comment: Why is this the answer this does not show your problem and solutions?

Answer (score 12):

You should try to use a `WebChromeClient` and implement `onProgressChanged` :

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.html#onProgressChanged(android.webkit.WebView, int)

```
mButterflyWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
           if (progress == 100) {
               // do screenshot
           }
        }
});
```

**EDIT** : to check if onPageStarted is loaded more than once :

```
mButterflyWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
           Log.d("WebView", "onPageStarted " + url);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
           Log.d("WebView", "onPageFinished " + url);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Doesn't work, the render hasn't finished although the newProgress = 100. What else?

Comment: Are your onPageFinished and/or onPageStarted called multiple times, or just once ?

Comment: I don't override those functions. Take a look on my codes above

Comment: Then override them and check if they are called multiple times. You can have a WebChromeClient & WebViewClient for the same WebView.

Comment: Can you explain more?

Comment: Just once, not multiple times :[

Comment: I found out that the problem is I have to touch to the render can be finished http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15127762/webview-fails-to-render-until-touched-android-4-2-2

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22212271/android-webview-webchromeclient-inaccurate-progress-value-in-onprogresschanged

Comment: Did not work for me. Traces showed that onProgressChanged with argument 100 is called even earlier than onPageFinished. The solution that worked for me is based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/20592188/4133096.

Comment: thanks! the `onProgressChanged` is the first time this works correctly for me.

Answer (score 10):

The best way to detect if a page has rendered is to use the [onPageCommitVisible](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onPageCommitVisible(android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String)) callback, available from API 23. `onPageLoadFinished` is not suitable, since it's delivered too soon (when the HTML is processed, but not yet rendered).

webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

```
    @Override
     public void onPageCommitVisible (WebView view, 
            String url)
    }
```

}

Comment: I disagree. I've found that the following sequence is triggered: `onPageCommitVisible` -> `onProgressChanged` -> `onPageFinished`

Answer (score 5):

You can do it like this, in your WebView:

```
@Override
public void invalidate() {
    super.invalidate();

    if (getContentHeight() > 0) {
        // WebView has displayed some content and is scrollable.
    }
}
```

Thanks to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14678910/1310343

Answer (score 0):

The renderer will not finish rendering when the OnPageFinshed method is called or the progress reaches 100% so both methods don't guarantee you that the view was completely rendered.

But you can figure out from OnLoadResource method what has been already rendered and what is still rendering. And this method gets called several times.

```
        @Override
        public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onLoadResource(view, url);
           // Log and see all the urls and know exactly what is being rendered and visible. If you wanna know when the entire page is completely rendered, find the last url from log and check it with if clause and implement your logic there.
            if (url.contains("assets/loginpage/img/ui/forms/")) {
                // loginpage is rendered and visible now.
               // your logic here.

            }
        }
```

Answer (score -2):

**Kotlin solution**

**First Solution**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    val webView : WebView = findViewById(R.id.webView)
    webView.webViewClient = MyWebViewClient()
 }

private class MyWebViewClient : WebViewClient() {
    override fun onPageStarted(view: WebView?, url: String?, favicon: Bitmap?) {
        println("Load Started")
    }
    override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView, url: String) {
        println("Load Finished")
    }
  }
}
```

**Second Solution**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    val webView : WebView = findViewById(R.id.webView)
    webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
        override fun onPageStarted(view: WebView?, url: String?, favicon: Bitmap?) {
            println("Load Started")
        }
        override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView, url: String) {
            println("Load Finished")
        }
     }
 }
```

Both solution actually same. So onPageStarted function run when page started to load in the other hang onPageFinished function works when page loaded entirely. You may want to write your as an example loadFinishedRun() function inside onPageFinished funtion.

Answer (score -3):

```
private class CfdWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        Log.v(TAG, "shouldOverrideUrlLoading: " + url);;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        Log.v(TAG, "onPageFinished: " + url);

        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: there wasn't another answer just above when I wrote my answer. So we both gave you the same answer :)